# React native header not pop up smoothly when navigate

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have two `StackNavigator` in a `DrawerNavigator`, when I direct between the two `StackNavigators`, I can see lag in rendering process. For example, I can see the header drop down from the top but not smoothly. How can I make it smooth or make it not "drop down"? This happens in real Iphone X & Iphone 6 & Simulator.

In my `navigator.js`

```
const homeNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    home: homeScreen,
    ...
})

const nav1Navigator = createStackNavigator({
    screen1: Screen1,
    ...
})

const MyNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    home: homeNavigator,
    nav1: { screen:nav1Navigator } 
})
```

in my `homeScreen.js`, I have a header

```
homeScreen.navigationOptions = navData => {
    return {
        drawerLabel:()=>{return ...},
        headerTitle: () => (
            // my header title with a image
            <IconText text="myTitle" image='../assets/pic.png' />
        ),
        headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item title="Menu"
                    iconName={'ios-list'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        navData.navigation.toggleDrawer();
                    }}
                />
            </HeaderButtons>
        ),
    }
};
```

in my `Screen1.js`,

```
Screen1.navigationOptions = navData => {
    return {
        headerLeft: () => (
            <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                <Item title="Menu"
                    iconName={'ios-arrow-back'}
                    onPress={() => {
                        navData.navigation.navigate('home');
                    }}
                />
            </HeaderButtons>
        )
    }
}
```

At the very first moment of a screen loaded, I can see the header is also there but in a wrong place, then it is "positioned" to the correct place.
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Solve this by upgrading to react navigation 5.x